# Using QuickFix/n to read a FIX log file

Tags: c#, file, quickfix

I have a FIX format log file and a data structure I've built myself in C#. What I want to do is to run the log file in QuickFix and build my own event listener. In that listener, I'll convert the FIX types into the types I need and fill my DS.

I've been going through the QuickFix tutorials and examples, but couldn't figure it out. I don't need it to go through a network or anything like that.

Please help and thank you,
Yonatan

Comment: I am not sure that I understand you, quickfix provides a good data structure for the messages already

Comment: the part about my DS is actually irrelevant. I just want to use QuickFix to parse a FIX log file and fire the appropriate OnMessage events.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of this question then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13160132/how-to-replay-a-quickfix-log  Additionally you should look at the test server that comes with the quickfix download (it does on java I presume it does on other distributions - if not you could use the java one).  The test server will just act as a dummy server replying to your fix session in a simple way. I have adapted it to mimic one of our brokers more closely.

Comment: another related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430806/reading-quickfix-log-file

Comment: I don't understand your use-case.  Are you just doing post-session analysis?

Comment: I am building a trading simulator into which i'll be able to plug my automated trading algorithm. I want to use the FIX log as the traffic in the simulator and have my algorithm "act" in that trading environment.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  A log would be good input for a fake market feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the QuickFIX ports provide this functionality.  At best, you could build a simple app that could read the logfile line-by-line and pass each line to QF's `Message(string)` constructor.  To convert that `Message` to a more specific type, you can feed it to a more-specific-type constructor, such as `ExecutionReport(Message)`.

The above are for the original C++ QF.  The other ports (QF/J and QF/n) should have similar mechanisms.

You will not be able to use the MessageCracker to fire OnMessage() events because you're not actually listening on a session.  Instead, I'd recommend using a switch or doing an overload based on message class arguments.